# How to prevent a specific child component from rerendering after performing an action in React

Tags: reactjs

In my react component their is a Panel which  has a label and a Component similar to react-filter-multiselect. There are 4 buttons outside of this panel (EDIT, SAVE, CANCEL, BACK). Onclick of EDIT --> SAVE CANCEL BACK will be visible and EDIT will be hidden. Also multiselect component will  get enabled onClick of EDIT button.

After selecting the data(moving items to be selected to right using arrow button in multiselect) in Multiselect user clicks the save button so that the selected data gets saved in the database.

Problem here is I want to maintain the state of Multiselect component and don't want to rerender that component after SAVE is clicked and also show the EDIT button back and disable Multiselect with the selected data after 
SAVE.

My code structure:

```
onSave() =>
{
```

1.save the values selected in Multiselect(rightData)

2.Show EDIT button

3.Disable the Multiselect component with it's current state and don't re 
render it(The value selected before save should be maintained)

```
}

render()

{
```

SAVE,CANCEL,EDIT,BACK button

```
<Panel>
label
```

Multiselect

```
</Panel>
}
```

How can I achieve this?
EDIT :

```
export default class User extends Component {


  static propTypes = {

    actions: PropTypes.object,
    params: PropTypes.object

  }

    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
      this.state = { errors: {}, showButton:false};
      this.state = this.getInitState(props);
      this.intitialize(); 
       }

    intitialize()
       {
        this.username = '';
        } 

     getInitState(props) 
         {
           return {username: undefined};
          }



     componentDidMount() 
         {
        this.loadUser(this.props);
        const {params: {username}} = this.props;
        const {USERNAME} = 'string';
        this.props.actions.loadList({USERNAME: username});
          }

     componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) 
         {
        if(nextProps.value!==this.props.value)
          {
        this.loadUser(props);
         }
        }     

     loadUser = (props) => 
        {
       const {params: {username}} = props;
       this.setState({username: username});
          }

      onEdit = () =>
        {
          this.setState({showButton:true});
         }

        Submit = () =>
        {
  this.props.actions.update({USER_NAME: username}).then((ret) => {
          if (ret.error) {
  this.props.actions.error('Error', ret.payload._error || 'Error loading         user data.');
           }
            else
          {
    this.props.actions.success('Success', 'Update was successful.');
            this.setState({showButton:false});
         }
        });
      }


onChange = (rightData, leftData) => {

    //dosomething

    }



 render() {

  const {username} = this.state;
  const {userData, actions} = this.props;
  const showHide = {'display' : this.state.showButton ? 'block' : 'none'};
  const showHide1 = {'display' : !this.state.showButton ? 'block' : 'none'};

        return (
          <div>

          <div className="pull-left"
         <ButtonToolbar>
  <Button className="button" bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.onEdit.bind(this)}  style = {showHide1} >Edit</Button>

 <Button className="button"  bsStyle="primary"   onClick {this.Submit.bind(this)} style = {showHide}>Save</Button>

  <Button className="button" bsStyle="primary"  style={showHide}>Cancel</Button>

  <Link to = 'service/' className = "btn btn-primary" role ="button">Back</Link> 
              </ButtonToolbar>

        </div>
        <br/>

        <form style={{width:1600}}>
          <Panel header = "department map" >
          <label>User name  :  {username} </label>
         <br/>
        <br/>

     <div>
        <Multiselect leftColConfig={leftColConfig} rightColConfig={rightColConfig} height={500} leftData={userData.data} rightData = {rightData} onChange={this.onChange} />    
        </div>
        </Panel>
        </form>

          </div>
          );
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: Please use proper code blocks.

Comment: I added my code @DoronBrikman